# Egg of a dove in my flowerpot

Tags: eggs

A dove just laid an egg in my flowerpot, on the window on the third floor. I really wanted to let it hatch, however, my wife said the chick has no chance to survive in this environment, it will surely fall and die. So, I thought maybe it is better to take the egg and eat it - this will at least save the dove the incubation time.

But, I have no idea if and how it is possible to eat an egg of a dove?

Comment: The eggs of all birds are pretty much the same in terms of edibility, although the flavor and obviously the size vary.  I am not sure I would want to eat an egg from a wild bird, since I don't know what if any pathogens they may carry.

Comment: That egg is also very likely to be fertilized and if it's a city dove, it may contain contaminants.  your initial idea of letting hatch might be the better than interfering ;) `life wants to be`.

Comment: You need to save pennies to eat a wild bird's egg?  Leave nature alone and it will leave you alone.  If the safety of the hatchling really worries you, ask a wildlife expert, not cooks.

Comment: @CareyGregory: From nature's point of view, I don't see any difference between eating a dove's egg and a hen's egg... On the contrary, the industry of hen's eggs causes much more discomfort to the hens: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/france/10238118/French-farmers-threaten-to-slaughter-hens-amid-egg-price-protest.html

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi - But your wife's theory that the egg can't survive is totally unfounded.  Birds raise chicks on narrow window sills and perches all over the world and the chicks rarely fall.  Justifying killing it by saying you're saving chickens is silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [American Dove Association](http://www.doveline.com/html/dove-information.html):

> **How many eggs do doves lay?**
>   Most doves lay two eggs; some species only lay one. Wild doves are notorious for infertile eggs.
>
> **Why do foreign doves abandon their eggs or young?**
>   Abandoning eggs may be due to biting pests (lice, mites), noises that frighten brooding birds, or overcrowding and fighting. Frightened doves will abandon young, or if the nest is disturbed in any way, parents may refuse to care for the young.

There is a chance the egg was not fertilized, and there is also a chance the bird could have had pests (whether or not that affects the egg, I do not know).

Based on this info, if it was me, I'd steer clear.